# Update Picturebox image

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I'm using a picture box as a 'preview' screen for a webbrowser control on a another winform. It works well apart from that in order to update the picturebox control I'm finding that the code needs to run twice (double click the button) linked to the below code. Any ideas why the picturebox isn't updating in the first pass to show the newly navigated page?

```
Private Sub mOutput_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mOutput.Click


    If Not mFiles.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then

        Formloading.fDisplay.WebBrowser1.Navigate(folderloc.ToString & "\" & mFiles.SelectedItem.ToString)

    End If

    Dim Bounds As System.Drawing.Rectangle
    Dim outputscreen As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim graph As System.Drawing.Graphics
    Dim LO As Integer = 0

    With Bounds
        .Height = fDisplay.WebBrowser1.Height
        .Width = fDisplay.WebBrowser1.Width
        .X = Formloading.fDisplay.Location.X
        .Y = Formloading.fDisplay.Location.Y
        .Size = Formloading.fDisplay.Size

    End With
    outputscreen = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(Bounds.Width, Bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)
    graph = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(outputscreen)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(Bounds.X, Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Bounds.Size, Drawing.CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    PictureBox1.Image = outputscreen


End Sub
```

Comment: When you call WebBrowser.Navigate() then the browser merely *starts* navigating to the url.  Takes a while, blink of an eye when it is a file.  But that blink isn't short enough, you make the screenshot too soon.  It is okay at the second click since the browser already displays the file content.  You need to move the screenshot code into an event handler for the WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted event.

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for your reply... I've fixed the issue in the end and moved to using a form with labels rather than a webrowser.